# Enable or disable @auth_basic() programmatically

Tags: python, bottle

I'm trying to use the Bottle framework `@auth_basic(check_credentials)` decorator within my program but I would like to be able to enable it or disable it based on a choice made by the user in program settings.

I've tried to do a `if` inside the `check_credentials` to return `True` if the setting is `False` but I'm still getting the login popup which is always returning `True`. I would like to not get the popup at all.

Any idea how I could achieve that?

```
def check_credentials(user, pw):
    if auth_enabled == True:
        username = "test"
        password = "test"
        if pw == password and user == username:
            return True
        return False
    else:
        return True

@route('/')
@auth_basic(check_credentials)
def root():
    # ---page content---
```

Comment: can you explain what framework you use or show some code?

Comment: Sorry, I only added the bottle tag and did no mention of it into the text.

Comment: have you tried logging value of `auth_enabled` inside the check function?

Comment: Yes, auth_enabled value is fine. The basic auth popup is showed as soon as the decorator is added to a route. I need to intercept it before it is showed.

Comment: @morpheus65535 I updated the answer with a custom auth_basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP Auth is popping because you are using the decorator from the bottle framework and this is a default behavior [link](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L3142).

What your setting actually do is always letting everyone in, not to disable the HTTP pop up. What you need to do is to implement another "middleware" that checks for the password.

```
from bottle import route, Response, run, HTTPError, request

auth_enabled = True


def custom_auth_basic(check, realm="private", text="Access denied"):
    ''' Callback decorator to require HTTP auth (basic).
        TODO: Add route(check_auth=...) parameter. '''
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*a, **ka):
            if auth_enabled:
                user, password = request.auth or (None, None)
                if user is None or not check(user, password):
                    err = HTTPError(401, text)
                    err.add_header('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="%s"' % realm)
                    return err
                return func(*a, **ka)
            else:
                return func(*a, **ka)

        return wrapper
    return decorator


def check_credentials(user, pw):
    if auth_enabled:
        username = "test"
        password = "test"
        if pw == password and user == username:
            return True
        return False
    else:
        return True


@route('/')
@custom_auth_basic(check_credentials)
def root():
    return Response("Test")


run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```