# Custom basic authentication function not working with Bottle hook

Tags: python-2.7, bottle

I cannot make this work using `bottle.hook('before_request')`, any idea why the basic auth popup never show?

```
from bottle import *

auth_enabled = True

@hook('before_request')
def custom_auth_basic():
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*a, **ka):
            if auth_enabled:
                user, password = request.auth or (None, None)
                if user is None or not check_credentials(user, password):
                    err = HTTPError(401, "Access denied")
                    err.add_header('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Private"')
                    return err
                return func(*a, **ka)
            else:
                return func(*a, **ka)

        return wrapper
    return decorator

def check_credentials(user, pw):
    username = "test"
    password = "test"
    if pw == password and user == username:
        return True
    return False

@route('/')
def root():
    return Response("Test")


run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

I cannot get it to work and to be totally honest, I do not fully understand those 3 nested functions and how they are called. It's based on a previous question I had: [Enable or disable @auth_basic() programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630946/enable-or-disable-auth-basic-programmatically)

Thanks!

Comment: All I can offer is advice: if you don't understand your own code, then it's unlikely that SO can help you. I suggest you spend time reading/experimenting until you understand how that code works. (Not trying to be snarky here; genuinely trying to help you.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I truly appreciate it. In the last 10 months O’ve learn Python from scratch and write a program of a couple of thousand lines of code. I understand every part of it but this one, I doesn’t get to understand it. Clearly I’m missing something but some help would be appreciated :-)